# How to blend multiple images with equal weights using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make a function that inputs an array of images, and then blend all the images into 1, with equal weights, here is my current code which only works if the amount images is the some number 2^n, like 4,8,16...

```
def Blend(imgs):
    num = len(imgs)
    p = int(math.log2(num))
    for i in range(1,p+1):
        twos = 2**i
        for j in range(0, num):
            if(j % twos != 0):
                pass
            else:
                index2 = j+(2**(i-1))
                imgs[j] = cv.addWeighted(imgs[j], 0.5, imgs[index2], 0.5, 1.0)

    return imgs[0]
```

The code above is a little bit convoluted, so i'll try to explain using image [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wepw.png)

I've searched some code online and got this code below

```
def Blend(imgs):
    canvas = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), dtype = "uint8")
    n = len(imgs)
    beta = np.divide(1,n)
    for i in range(0,n):
        canvas = cv.addWeighted(canvas, 1.0, imgs[i], beta, 0.0)

    return canvas
```

Unfortunately, the end result is so bad and far from my expectation, what i wanted is that the end result will be the same as if i used my first code above, but like i said, there is some limitation with the amount of inputs and i don't really like how that code works in the first place, i need some better and perhaps more efficient alternative to blend multiple images together...

Edit: also is it actually possible to do it in parallel using multiprocessing?

Comment: Your first code should be better since it does fewer addWeighted calls which I assume being expensive? You just need to remember once two pictures are added, the new weight is combined. So you can add any two pictures, just use a helper data structure to remember the weights

Comment: well, yeah but the difference is only 1 call, but that's not worth of the limitation having that  2^n amount of images, unless if it's the only way, then i will accept that.

btw, it already store/remember the pictures that are added in their respective index, for example the result of image 0 and 1 will be stored as image 0

Comment: I don't have time right now for a complete answer, but you could concatenate all of the images into an array and then use [`numpy.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) along the appropriate axis.

Comment: i recently tried to use imageio along side with Pillow-SIMD and numpy instead of using OpenCV, the result is good but not the way i expected it to be. btw maybe you could show me a code example about your answer :)

Comment: @dwiandhika Since you didn't tag me in your comment, I didn't know you'd responded. Assuming your images are in an array `imgs` with shape `n, height, width, channels`, you'd use `avg_img = np.mean(imgs.astype(np.double), 0).astype(np.uint8)`. Note that this only works because all of the images have equal weight.

Comment: @beaker i see, sorry i didn't tag you, i didn't know it's a feature here, anyway thanks, i already done it, i use numpy to blend multiple images instead of opencv